# Error 500 on product detail page in Magento2

Tags: product, magento-2.2.5, http-error-500

When I am trying to open product detail page I am getting error Http Error 500.
Also, no log is generated to fetch any error. Everything else works fine except the product detail page.

I did

```
cache:clean,
cache:flush,
indexer:reindex.
```

Then Deleted Browser Cache.

Comment: Check web server log error.log file inside /var/apache2/log/error.log

Comment: or change developer mode and check the issue up in front.

Comment: It is developer mode only

Comment: Can u tell me where can i find error.log in server

Comment: /var/log/apache2/error.log and if you're using nginx replace apache2 with nginx

Comment: @Parthavi, Rename file inside pub/error folder from local.xml.sample to local.xml

Comment: Are you using a custom theme? also have you installed any custom extensions